# Python retrieve element from list using index number

Tags: python, list, indexing

I've been googling around for the answer to this question, but have had no luck to date.

Python lists.

I have a list with 3 rows of data in it.

```
K[0]
K[1]
K[2]
```

If for example I wish to go to a specific index number within the list discribed obove, say k[2] index 127, how do I do that. I want to be able to print the contents of that element at that index.

All help greatfully appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Do you simply mean:

```
print(K[2][127])
```

You can access sub-indices like you would any other.

Comment: Thank you all very much! As it turns out my problem was not understanding the correct syntax to use. I kept getting unhashable errors no matter what I tried. Headache solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can index into the container at `K[2]` exactly as you indexed into the container `K`:

```
element = K[2][127]
```

Example:

```
        # 0  1  2
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], # l[0]
         [4, 5, 6], # l[1]
         [7, 8, 9]] # l[2]
>>> l[2][0]
7
```

Comment: Thank you all very much! As it turns out my problem was not understanding the correct syntax to use. I kept getting unhashable errors no matter what I tried. Headache solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing a 2d array. To access single elements in a 2d array, simply use the double `[]` notation:

```
K[2][127] # index 127
```

Comment: Thank you all very much! As it turns out my problem was not understanding the correct syntax to use. I kept getting unhashable errors no matter what I tried. Headache solved :-)